# firebase.apps.length of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase

#### Environment

- Operating System version:  Windows 11
- Browser version: Chrome
- Firebase SDK version: 9.0.2
- Firebase Product: database

#### firebase.apps.length of undefined

##### Issue:

I dont know what happened today morning it opened my code and it shows something like
app.firestore() is not a function and shows firebase.apps.length of undefined

##### Code:

```js
 import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
 import 'firebase/firestore'
 import 'firebase/auth'
 
const app = !firebase.apps.length ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : firebase.app()
 
const db = app.firestore()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The syntax for Firebase has changed in v9, as everything is now modular/functional. You can now safely get an app with:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
```

I highly recommend keeping Firebase's own [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) and this [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) handy.

---

Alternatively, you can keep using the older syntax by using the [compatibility mode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#about_the_compat_libraries) of the newer SDKs, by importing from the `compat` path.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

In that case the rest of your code stays unchanged.

Comment: Check this,  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#web-namespaced-api