# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_app.firebase.apps')

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

Can someone help with this typeerror. I am trying to connect to firebase through an expo go app and this error will come up at every place I have a firebase. I was guessing that the issue was with the imports as the initial import was outdated for firebase. If I am not doing the import correctly I would love to know.

My code is as follows:

```
// @refresh reset
import React , {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { initializeApp, firebase } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';
import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat'

const firebaseConfig = {
//info for database
};

if (firebase.apps.length === 0){ //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR KEEPS COMING UP FIRST
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}


const db = firebase.firestore()
const chatsRef = db.collection('chats')

export default function App() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        readUser()
        const unsubscribe = chatsRef.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
            const messagesFirestore = querySnapshot
                .docChanges()
                .filter(({ type }) => type === 'added')
                .map(({ doc }) => {
                    const message = doc.data()
                    //createdAt is firebase.firestore.Timestamp instance
                    //https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp
                    return { ...message, createdAt: message.createdAt.toDate() }
                })
                .sort((a, b) => b.createdAt.getTime() - a.createdAt.getTime())
            appendMessages(messagesFirestore)
        })
        return () => unsubscribe()
    }, [])

    const appendMessages = useCallback(
        (messages) => {
            setMessages((previousMessages) => GiftedChat.append(previousMessages, messages))
        },
        [messages]
    )

    async function readUser() {
        const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
        if (user) {
            setUser(JSON.parse(user))
        }
    }
    async function handlePress() {
        const _id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)
        const user = { _id, name }
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))
        setUser(user)
    }
    async function handleSend(messages) {
        const writes = messages.map((m) => chatsRef.add(m))
        await Promise.all(writes)
    }

    if (!user) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Enter your name" value={name} onChangeText={setName} />
                <Button onPress={handlePress} title="Enter the chat" />
            </View>
        )
    }
    return <GiftedChat messages={messages} user={user} onSend={handleSend} />
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        padding: 30,
    },
    input: {
        height: 50,
        width: '100%',
        borderWidth: 1,
        padding: 15,
        marginBottom: 20,
        borderColor: 'gray',
    },
})
```

Comment: Kindly check this link for your issue: [a click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69143642/firebase-apps-length-of-undefined)!

Answer (score 0):

Dont use firebase for web apps for react-native apps. It will work for the easiest things but is not optimized for it and you will have a lot of trouble with it when further developing your app. I did it too and it didnt work out eventually.
Use [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/). That will work without any problems and doesnt take long to set up

Comment: I’m using expo go and looked into react native firebase. It says that I cannot use it with expo go apps. Are there any alternatives that are compatible with expo go apps?

Comment: No there not. You cant use ExpoGo after adding firebase react-native. Use npx build-android/ios and then npx run-android/ios to build on simulator or real device.